# InstallData not running (Magento 2.2.6)

Tags: magento2, installdata

I'm trying to make my module's `InstallData.php` work but it's not even running.

Before every test i delete the module's entry from `setup_module` table.

I thought the namespace and path were the issue, i tried with `TwoKnet\ICircle` but it's not working either.

Here's the code:

```
namespace _2000net\iCircle\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use \Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\Address;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

private $eavSetupFactory;

private $eavConfig;

private $attributeResource;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Attribute $attributeResource
) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->attributeResource = $attributeResource;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {

    error_log('is running');

    try {

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Customer::ENTITY,
            'icircle_id',
            [
                'type'         => 'int',
                'label'        => 'iCircle ID',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0
            ]
        );

        $customerAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'icircle_id');
        $customerAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', [ 'adminhtml_customer' ]);
        $this->attributeResource->save($customerAttribute);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY,
            'icircle_id',
            [
                'type'         => 'int',
                'label'        => 'iCircle ID',
                'input'        => 'text',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0
            ]
        );

        $addressAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Address\AttributeProvider::ENTITY, 'icircle_id');
        $addressAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', [ 'adminhtml_customer_address' ]);
        $this->attributeResource->save($addressAttribute);

    } catch (\Exception $exception) {
        error_log($exception->getMessage());
    }

}

}
```

Comment: I guess it is probably long-resolved, but given that noone else can suggest stuff you didn't already think of, on this I would say that you should check all logs: `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (or wherever apache logs live); your php error log https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531703/how-do-i-log-errors-and-warnings-into-a-file (or set values in relevant `php.ini`); finally all logs under `[magento_root]/var/log`. `tail` these files whilst4 upgrading. Also maybe implement Psr/Log/LoggerInterface, logging 'critical` messages to see if it even instantiates the class

Answer (score 1):

You can try following patching in order to  run above code :

> Location : Vendor/Module/Setup/Patch/Data/CustomerAttribute.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface as SetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;


class CustomerAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var SetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var Attribute
     */
    private $entityAttribute;

    /**
     * UpdateProductsAttributes constructor.
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     * @param Attribute $entityAttribute
     * @param SetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        Attribute $entityAttribute,
        SetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->entityAttribute = $entityAttribute;
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
       ...................
.........................
........................
        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Run command : `php bin/magento  setup:upgrade` 
**Note : Verify patch  applied or not in patch_list table in db .
Thanks**

Comment: Thanks but i'm going to redistribute this module so i need InstallData.php to work

Answer (score 0):

This example module should help you further:

> https://mage2gen.com/load/355507f7-9c5e-445f-a97d-32d736b9fbb4?main_version=2

Perhaps the module version is already set in the `setup_module` table but in that case you can easily change to a upgrade script in the example module.

Comment: _Before every test i delete the module's entry from setup_module table._